# MongoDB PHP library - code works in terminal but not on browser

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have installed the MongoDB PHP library using pecl by following the official documentation given on http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php

I have created a collection named 'ma' containing two documents 'd1' and 'd2', through the mongo shell.

I am trying to connect to d1 through this file: connect.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->ma->d1;
echo "Done\n";
echo $collection;
?>
```

connect.php runs on my terminal and gives this output:

```
$ php connect.php
Done
ma.d1
```

But on the browser it gives this error: This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

My machine is 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
PHP version: 5.5.9.
MongoDB shell and server version: 3.6.2.
Apache server version: 2.4.7.

I am sure the driver was installed correctly because I get this:

```
$ php --ri mongodb | grep version
MongoDB extension version => 1.4.0
libbson bundled version => 1.9.2
libmongoc bundled version => 1.9.2
```

I'm new to this driver. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the use of PEAR/PECL. For all major PHP extensions, you will find pre-packaged and tested binaries right where you also found those for PHP itself. This will rule out that anything was wrong with the installation itself. Then, you can enable/disable extensions depending on whether the code is served by Apache or run on the commandline, check if both are enabled.

Comment: BTW: You need to check the error logs. Doing so, you could have solved the problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but since the official PHP site gave me the option to use PECL, I followed it. And I got it to work, so it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the mongodb.so extension directive in the php.ini that is used by apache?

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php

Comment: Yes, I added that line during the installation but turns out I was supposed to restart Apache after that. I've answered my own question but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After adding extension = mongodb.so to the php configuration file (/etc/php5/cli/php.ini in my case), you have to restart the Apache server.

```
sudo killall apache2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Also, not sure if this was related to MongoDB or just to Apache, but I got this error on restart: "apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message."

So I followed this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/256018

Finally, use this code to ensure the extension is being loaded:

```
<?php
echo extension_loaded("mongodb") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";
?>
```